# How can I overwrite the dependency in a certain module (sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet)?

Tags: sapui5

I want to extend the logic of `DataProviderBase.js` used by `SpreadsheetExport.js` (to only take into account hierarchical level '0' to determine fetched records and set the next skip value).

I basically want to overwrite the reference to the source file for the dependency for `SpreadsheetExport` in the AMD syntax define of `sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet`.

```js
sap.ui.define([
        'sap/ui/core/Core',
        './ExportDialog',
        'sap/ui/base/EventProvider',
        'sap/ui/Device',
        'sap/ui/export/SpreadsheetExport', // <--- This needs to point to my own implementation
        'sap/base/Log',
        'sap/ui/export/ExportUtils'
    ],
    function(Core, ExportDialog, EventProvider, Device, SpreadsheetExport, Log, ExportUtils) {

})
```

How can I achieve this?

Update: I managed to get the result that I wanted, but I had to extend `sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet` and copy the entire code of `build()` and `_createBuildPromise()`, which is something I would like to avoid to do if possible.

Comment: Just an idea without having tried it: maybe you can add an entry for the resource roots in your bootstrap entry. This would of course overwrite it globally in the application, not just inside your module.